# How to define a global variable in RAML

Tags: raml, raml-1.0

I want to use a global variable in RAML file:

```
#%RAML 1.0

title: MyTitle
myVariable: http://example.com
version: v1
baseUri: {myVariable}/{version}
```

but it doesn't work.
Does RAML actually allow that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't allow to level vars like that. However it does allow you to define `baseUriParameters` like so:

```
#%RAML 1.0
---

baseUri: http://{myVariable}.com
baseUriParameters:
  myVariable:
    type: string
    enum: [ us-east, us-west, emea, apac ]
    default: us-east
```